# error in converting string id to double when executing using scalar

Tags: sql, vb.net

i'm trying to make a form show when a user enters an id using the inputbox function that matches one from the database but i get string conversion to double error

```
      Try
        con.Open()
        Dim x As String
        x = InputBox("Please Input Student ID")
        Dim command3 As SqlClient.SqlCommand
        command3 = con.CreateCommand
        command3.CommandText = "SELECT Student_ID from studentdb1 where Student_ID='" & x.ToUpper & "'"

        If command3.ExecuteScalar > 0 Then

            studform.Height = 717
            studform.Width = 750
            questions_panel.Hide()
        Else
            MsgBox("student details not found", vbCritical)
        End If


        con.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Comment: Always use parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting errors.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong in many ways. Firstly, what's the point of converting the user input to upper-case if it's supposed to be a number?

Secondly, why are you wrapping a number in single-quotes? Do you wrap numbers in double-quotes in VB? If not, why wrap numbers in single-quotes SQL? If you're going to use SQL, learn SQL.

Thirdly, you test whether the value returned from the database is greater than zero. What do you expect it to be if there's no match? Less than zero? If so, why? If not, why are you doing that comparison?

I'm not going to teach you how to use parameters here but it is something that you must learn, so do so before using databases again. To fix the code you have got, either use:

```vb
command3.CommandText = "SELECT Student_ID FROM studentdb1 WHERE Student_ID = " & x

If command3.ExecuteScalar() IsNot DBNull.Value Then
```

or:

```vb
command3.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(Student_ID) FROM studentdb1 WHERE Student_ID = " & x

If command3.ExecuteScalar() > 0 Then
```

EDIT:

As it is now apparent that the `Student_ID` column contains text and not numbers, the appropriate variations would be this:

```vb
command3.CommandText = $"SELECT Student_ID FROM studentdb1 WHERE Student_ID = '{x}'"

If command3.ExecuteScalar() IsNot DBNull.Value Then
```

or this:

```vb
command3.CommandText = $"SELECT COUNT(Student_ID) FROM studentdb1 WHERE Student_ID = '{x}'"

If command3.ExecuteScalar() > 0 Then
```

Comment: the id is mixed with letters like "STA01"

Comment: Then why would you think that comparing the result of that query to a number would be a good idea? See my edit above.

Comment: `If command3.ExecuteScalar() > 0 Then` I don't get it. ExecuteScalar returns an Object; the first column of the first row of the result set, if successful, in this case a string of a null. How is it compared to zero?

Comment: @Mary, the fourth query should have been using `COUNT` like the second was, which I have now fixed.